# Is there any way to set PPTP on UDP Protocol?

Tags: centos, vpn, tcp, pptp, udp

In our network,many web site has been filtered ,so we should use VPN or Socks ,They reduce any tcp connection speed by dropping random packet (Than post and get on http),So ssh,pptp and ... are so slow.

Now I wanna to connect to my pptp server by UDP, because it will not dropped it the way.

Is there any way to configure pptp server on UDP and configure pptp client to connect to pptp server on UDP?
( My Server Operation System Is CentOs )

Comment: what is your client SO?

Comment: Ask your network administrator or obtain permission through the proper channels. If it's still not allowed, you're out of luck.

Comment: What makes you believe UDP would not have the same problem?

Comment: @Zoredache Because it works:)

Answer (score 2):

PPTP can not use UDP. (In fact it doesn't run over TCP either - it's a combination of TCP control channel (which shouldn't affect speed) and GRE data channel).

The only widespread VPN protocol that runs over UDP is OpenVPN.